# Why does my lambda expression work, but actionPerformed() method doesn't?

Tags: java

I'm writing this very simple, beginner Java program just to learn and practice. The program is basically just a button that prints out "Hey!" and makes an image icon appear when clicked.

This is my code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    JButton button;
    JLabel label;
    
    MyFrame() {
        
        ImageIcon pic = new ImageIcon("Dice.png");
        
        label = new JLabel();
        label.setIcon(pic);
        label.setBounds(150 ,250, 150, 150);
        label.setVisible(false);
        
        JButton button = new JButton();
        button.setBounds(100, 100, 200, 50);
        button.addActionListener(e->  { System.out.println("Hey!"); label.setVisible(true); });
        
        button.setText("I'm a button!");
        button.setFocusable(false);
        button.setHorizontalTextPosition(JButton.CENTER);
        button.setVerticalTextPosition(JButton.TOP);
        button.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 18));
        button.setForeground(Color.white);
        button.setBackground(Color.black);
        button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
    
        
        
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setSize(600, 600);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.add(button);
        this.add(label);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }
}
```

My actionPerformed() method is empty because even when I have code in there, and I pass "this" as my argument for Button.addActionListener(), the button just doesn't do what it's supposed to when I click it. However, what's interesting is when I use a lambda expression - and put the exact same specifications for what the button should do - it does work.

```
button.addActionListener(e->  { System.out.println("Hey!"); label.setVisible(true); });
```

I've seen instances where one or the other doesn't work, or both, but I can't find anything online where one works and the other doesn't.

Also, the reason I don't have a main function is because it's in another file where I create a new object of the MyFrame class to test everything out.

If anyone knows what's happening and could drop an answer that'd be great, thank you.

Edit: Here is my non working code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    JButton button;
    JLabel label;
    
    MyFrame() {
        
        ImageIcon pic = new ImageIcon("Dice.png");
        
        label = new JLabel();
        label.setIcon(pic);
        label.setBounds(150 ,250, 150, 150);
        label.setVisible(false);
        
        JButton button = new JButton();
        button.setBounds(100, 100, 200, 50);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        
        button.setText("I'm a button!");
        button.setFocusable(false);
        button.setHorizontalTextPosition(JButton.CENTER);
        button.setVerticalTextPosition(JButton.TOP);
        button.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 18));
        button.setForeground(Color.white);
        button.setBackground(Color.black);
        button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
    
        
        
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setSize(600, 600);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.add(button);
        this.add(label);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Hey!"); 
        label.setVisible(true);
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code you would be testing when not using the lambda?  Just looking at your code, the `actionPerformed()` method is empty, which means it won't do anything...

Comment: Where *exactly* have you tried putting this line: `button.addActionListener(this);`?

Comment: What *exactly* have you put inside `actionPerformed()` method?

Comment: Your code works for me, making some assumptions about what your non-working version looks like. As others have said: show your non-working code.

Comment: *just to learn and practice* - learn to use Swing the way it was designed. Don't use a null layout and setBounds(...) Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. Components should be added to the frame BEFORE the frame is made visible.

Comment: Ok I added in my non working code @tgdavies

Comment: Learning on trying. But before you try to do something you'd read the API JButton description carefully before you use it.

Comment: The non working code works for me -- depending on exactly what "doesn't do what it's supposed to when I click it" means.